# Why is $y'=\frac{x^2}{y^2}$ a Bernoulli equation and not a linear one, but $y'=-\frac{2y}{x}$ is Linear and not Bernoulli?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Im going through this book on differential equations:

[Differential Equations (Schaum's Outlines) 4th Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071824855)

In chapter 3, Supplementary Problems I have to determine whether an equation is homogeneous and/or linear, and if not linear, whether it is a Bernoulli equation.

---

Definition of a Linear equation:

$y' + p(x)y=q(x)$

Definition of a Bernoulli equation:

$y' + p(x)y=q(x)y^n$

---

I understand why:

$y'=\frac{x^2}{y^2}$

is a Bernoulli equation. It cannot be a Linear one because when we rearrange everything we get:

$y' + 0 = x^2 \cdot y^{-2}$

So we get:

$
n=-2 \\
p(x)=0 \\
q(x)=x^2
$

Because we have two $y$'s (although with a `-` sign in their powers, it doesn't matter), so we cannot formulate a Linear equation.

---

But here:

$y'=-\frac{2y}{x}$

is not a Bernoulli equation but a Linear one.

I can see why it is a Linear equation, if we rearrange things we get:

$y' + 2\frac{1}{x}\cdot y = 0$

So we get:

$
p(x)=2\frac{1}{x} \\
q(x)=0
$

But why cant it also be a Bernoulli equation with $q(x)=0$?

Comment: What are the definitions? Thinking hard about the definition will often give you the answer

Comment: okay, its 2 am, i reread everything and edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am currently taking a Differential Equations class and I think I might be able to help!

$y' = \frac{x^2}{y^2}$ is a Bernoulli's equation since it can be written in the form:

$$
y' + P(x)y = Q(x)y^n \\
\Downarrow \\
y'+ 0 = x^2(y^{-2}) \\
n=-2
$$

**NOTE: In order for an ODE to be considered a Bernoulli's ODE, n can not $= 0$ or $1$.

Since the $y$ is raised to the power $2$ in the ODE, where $2$ is not $1$ or $0$, then this ODE meets the requirements to be a Bernoulli's ODE.

If the $y$ was raised to the power of $1$, I believe it can then be solved as a linear ODE where we get:
$y' - (x^2)(\frac{1}{y})=0$

But it is raised to the power of 2, so it is a Bernoulli's ODE.

---

$y' = \frac{-2y}{x}$ is a linear ODE because it can be put into the linear ODE general form:
$$
y'+P(x)y = Q(x) \\
\Downarrow \\
y'+(\frac{2}{x})y=0
$$

Since y is raised to the power 1, the ODE does not meet the requirements necessary to be a Bernoulli's ODE as stated above ( y can not be raised to the power of 0 or 1).

---

Thus...

$y'= \frac{x^2}{y^2}$ is a Bernoulli's ODE and NOT a Linear ODE

&

$y'= \frac{-2y}{x}$ is a Linear ODE and NOT a Bernoulli's ODE

Hopefully, this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

The Bernoulli DE is a class of DE with a "trick". The important thing is the trick. And the trick is to substitute $u=y^{1-n}$, resulting in a linear DE in $u$.

This does obviously not work for $n=1$, giving a non-reversible transformation. For $n=0$ it does not make sense, as the term with $y^n$ would not contain $y$.